# Converting an empty string to nil in place?

Tags: ruby, string, null, in-place

I'm looking for a way to convert an empty string to `nil` in place using Ruby.  If I end up with a string that is empty spaces I can do

```
 "    ".strip!
```

This will give me the empty string `""`.

What I would like to be able to do is something like this.

```
"    ".strip!.to_nil!
```

This will get an in place replacement of the empty string with `nil`.  `to_nil!` would change the string to `nil` directly if it is `.empty?` otherwise if the string is not empty it would not change.

The key here is that I want it to happen directly rather than through an assignment such as

```
f = nil if f.strip!.empty?
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something... but what would the point be to do something to a string first and then set it to nil?  Might as well set the string to nil in the first place, right?

Comment: It cannot be done inplace. Are you interested only in in-place modifications? I created an answer with `String#presence` but it's not in-place (note that both inplace/rebindings are -usually- a bad practice).

Comment: I agree that they are usually a bad practice, I'm essentially trying to go around a road block that this type of solution would make it very easy.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The clean way is using `presence`.

Let's test it.

```
'    '.presence
# => nil


''.presence
# => nil


'text'.presence
# => "text"


nil.presence
# => nil


[].presence
# => nil


{}.presence
# => nil

true.presence
# => true

false.presence
# => nil
```

Please note this method is from Ruby on Rails v4.2.7
https://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence

NOTE: Not work on IRB, work with Ruby on Rails!

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Not working when creating Fastlane script(

Answer (score 4):

That isn't possible.

`String#squeeze!` can work in place because it's possible to modify the original object to store the new value. But the value `nil` is an object of a different class, so it cannot be represented by an object of class **String**.

Comment: That really goes to the heart of what I'm trying to do.  I essentially want to do an in place change that is changing types.  With all of the other magic surrounding Ruby with __send__, eval, etc...  I was thinking there might be a way to essentially find the object by object_id and switch it out from underneath itself.

Comment: That would be especially difficult with `nil` which is an immediate value. It always has 4 as the object_id.

Comment: Agreed; I guess what I'm really getting at is trying to trick the system into pointing from one object_id to another.  In the same way we can bypass private using send.

Answer (score 3):

I know I am bit late but you can write your own method for the String class, and run code in initializers:

```
class String
  def to_nil
    present? ? self : nil
  end
end
```

and then you will get:

```
'a'.to_nil
=> "a"
''.to_nil
=> nil
```

Of course you can also strip the string before checking if thats suits for you

Comment: `to_nil` is a very misleading method name.

Comment: Maybe there is a better name, this is not the issue. Look back at @bigtunacan question, he seeks for a function named `to_nil`.

Comment: curious, why is it misleading?

Comment: @ahnbizcad because you'd expect `s.to_nil.nil?` to always evaluate `true`, which is not the case.

Comment: This is literally `.presence` (RoR >= 4.2.7 as mentioned in `Martin K` answer)

Comment: @NBcrafts the question is about Ruby, not RoR.

Comment: Fair, though 1) I did mention that before your answer 2) presence is the accepted answer :shrug:

Answer (score 1):

Regex to the rescue! We can use `string[regexp]` which returns a `new_string` if there is a match or `nil` if the regex doesn't match (see documentation [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)).

```
''[/.+/] 
# => nil

'text'[/.+/] 
# => 'text'

# Caution 1: This doesn't work for strings which are just spaces
'   '[/.+/] 
# => '   '

# In these cases you can strip...
'   '.strip[/.+/] 
# => nil

# ...or use a more complicated regex:
'   '[/.*\S.*/]
# => nil
```

Comment: Nil safe version: `your_string&.match(/.+/)&.to_s`