# Convert an empty array to nil inplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code:

```
some_array = [] # Sometimes is filled, in this case it isn't
new_array = some_array || ['default', 'array', 'values']
```

Now, the `||` is not triggered, because `[] != nil`

Of course it can be solved by doing:

```
new_array = some_array
new_array = ['default', 'array', 'values'] if new_array.blank?
```

But I remember there is a function that does this in a single line, like:

```
[].filled_arr_or_nil # nil
['something'].filled_arr_or_nil # ['something']
```

Comment: You can also use something like: `new_array = some_array.present? ? some_array : [..]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't able to find the answer using a search engine, but StackOverflow gave me the answer with a similar question, but then about strings:

[Converting an empty string to nil in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45506288/782713)

The solution is to use [`presence`](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence)

Only available within Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
some_array = []
new_array = some_array.empty? ? ['default', 'array', 'values'] : some_array
```

This is just a conditional statement that uses [`empty?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) to check if `some_array` contains any elements and then returns the desired output